# Configuring SendGrid properly to send emails as Gmail sender

Tags: gmail, email, mailchimp, sendgrid

I am trying to set up emailing facility for a small non profit organization. We use a gmail account as our official email and all emails are sent from that sender.

Steps I already followed in SendGrid:

- Configured the Gmail Sender.
- Completed Domain Authentication, as recommended by their documentation even though my sender's email is not like @mynonprofit.org
- Ensure that my email contains unsubscribe option to comply with the rules.
- Tried both rich and simple text email.

Even after trying all these things the emails are

- Marked as spam in Gmails
- Yahoo mail boxes are either not reached or delivered after several days.
- Some organizational domains like, @myuniversity.edu is not receiving any email at all.

**Question**

Could anyone please help me how to configure SendGrid to make sure the emails are always sent to all my recipients as a legit content?

**Side note**

*I also tried another service called MailChimp and that seems to deliver all my emails properly. Using free version of both with default settings. Really confused what makes the configurations in SendGrid so vulnerable.*

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The questions has multiple questions but should include only one, by the other hand comparing two services might make the question primarily opinion-based. My suggestion is focus your question on "Is there any way to configure SendGrid to send emails from a Gmail sender and ensure no email is missed." and don't forget to include a brief description of your search/research efforts about this specific question as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén I tried to edit my post again, let me know if you think it requires any further changes. Really hoping to get some helpful comments from the community.

Comment: When you say `even though my sender's email is not like @mynonprofit.org` are you saying that your email address uses `@gmail.com`?

Comment: Yes we are using `@gmail.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Don’t Send Email From Domains You Don’t Control](https://sendgrid.com/blog/dont-send-email-from-domains-you-dont-control/), by SendGrid Team, dated January 3, 2017

> If you’re sending from gmail.com, outlook.com, or some other third party domain that neither you nor the customer on whose behalf you’d like to send control, I have bad news. You’re going to have to find a new way. Starting very soon, those messages are never going to get delivered. Both Google and Microsoft are planning to implement this policy very soon, and Yahoo has already made the change.

Related

- [How can I set up a Mailing List?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24193/88163)
- [My G Suite Gmail personal emails to people are being sent to spam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122594/881639)